# Find the top summed values and take 3

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

I have this code (not sure if it works as I can't test it):

```
var test = base.UnitOfWork.Session.Query<NutritionFact>()
                                  .Where(x => x.NutritionalServing.Id == servingId)
                                  .GroupBy(x => x.UserVerifiedFacts)
                                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum(e => e.UserVerifiedFacts.Count()))
                                  .Take(3)
                                  .Select(r => new
                                      {
                                          c = r.Key,
                                          Sum = r.Sum(x => x.UserVerifiedFacts.Count())
                                      })
                                  .ToList();
```

What I am trying to do is find all `NutritionFacts` that have the correct `servingId`. I then want to count for each of those `NutritionFacts` found the count of how many users verified the information. I then want to get the top 3 results and use them.

What I am doing now results in a "not implemented" error that apparently is because nhibernate sum can only handle no parameters.

[image]

Comment: could you please post the classes involved and how they relate. am not sure how would i query for "how many users verified the information" without that.

Comment: Ok. I will post a screenshot of the tables with the keys shown(otherwise too must useless columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
var test = ...Query<NutritionFact>()
             .Where(x => x.NutritionalServing.Id == servingId)
             .Select(x=> new { Nf= x, VfCount= x.UserVerifiedFacts.Count() })
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.VfCount))
             .Take(3)
             .ToList();
```

You don't need to use `Sum`. The `Sum` is for aggregating (summarizing) the grouped columns, but you want just to `Count()` the number of rows in related table for each specific `NuturitionFact`.

*It corresponds to this SQL statement (which is, I suppose, what you need)*

```
SELECT TOP 3 n.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserVerifiedFact uv WHERE uv.NuturitionFacts_Id = n.Id) AS NumbOfVer  
       FROM NutritionFact n 
       WHERE n.NutritionalServing_Id = @servingId
       ORDER BY NumbOfVer DESC
```